# Error reading data from SQL Server database using SqlDataReader

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have the following vb.net code

```
Protected Sub submit_date_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles submit_date.Click
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("GasNominationsConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        conn.Open()
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from MorningReport where readdate = " & "'" & datedisplay.text & "'"
            Dim sqlrd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            If sqlrd.HasRows Then sqlrd.Read()
            Me.Label6.Text = sqlrd.Item("NteesHR")

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

The problem I have is it doesn't read any data. The `datedisplay.text` is a text box populated using an ajax calendar extender and when I debug the data I can see it gets the correct date which is `22/08/2013` for this example. I then get the error

> Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

The problem I have is if I copy the SQL statement into SQL Server Management Studio and run it against the table it works fine and I get the result I want.

The SQL is

```
select * from MorningReport where readdate = '22/08/2013'
```

The format of the date in the sql table is 2013-08-22 with type date.

What am I missing?

Comment: When you debug your code what is in `cmd.CommandText` after that line executes?

Comment: "select * from MorningReport where ReadDate = '22/08/2013'"

Comment: And if you take that exact value, minus the double quotes at the beginning and end, does it execute correctly in SQL Server?

Comment: Yep perfectly.  Returns one row of about 20 fields.

Comment: Is there a field returned exactly named `NteesHR`?

Comment: You could possibly try `#22/08/2013#` instead.

Comment: yes there should be as one of the fields in the database is nteesHR.  I copied it directly from the design when I was first getting this error to rule it out.

Comment: using the # doesn't work.  Either way it jumps the sqlrd.read() and ends the if statement as the sqslrd.hasrows is false

Comment: Just should **absolutely use a parametrized query** instead of concatenating together your SQL! First of all, doing what you're doing now is in open invitation to **SQL injection** attacks, secondly it's slower, and thirdly, you get into issue like this with what format your dates - mishandled as strings - are...... don't do this! Use a **parameter** of type `DateTime` and all your problems go away immediately!

Comment: Its the datedisplay.text that's the issue as if I query a different field in the DB, say an INT then it works fine.  marc_s, I will endeavour to use your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

using [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) recommendation I used a parametrized query. Please see below. Cheers

```
Protected Sub submit_date_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles submit_date.Click

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("GasNominationsConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        conn.Open()
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "getMorningReportData"
            cmd.Parameters.Add("datedisplay", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateDisplay.Text
            Dim sqlrd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            If sqlrd.HasRows Then
                sqlrd.Read()

                Me.Label6.Text = sqlrd.Item("NteesHR")
            End If


        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```